# Staled kubernetes endpoints

Tags: akka, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I have a problem with staled kubernetes endpoints.  When a pod implementing a
service is gone, it's endpoint is not registered.  Even after I delete
the endpoints for the service with `kubectl delete ep service-name`
and restart the service the old pod's endpoints (not valid any more)
reappear in the endpoint list.  This is very problematic as I use the
service endpoint list for Akka cluster seed node list.

Does somebody know how to further debug the issue and eventually fix
it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known open issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47597